# jQuery countdown timer for minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create a jquery countdown timer, i tried as the following code but it does not work.what do i do?

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/tbosn210/

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    
    var timer2 = $("5:01");
    var timer = timer2.split(':');
    //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
    var minutes = parseInt(timer[0],10);
    var seconds = parseInt(timer[1],10);
    --seconds;
    minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
    if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
    $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Move your timer2 declaration out of setInterval function, assign new value of time to timer2 at the end of execution to continue.

Working Snippet:

```js
var timer2 = "5:01";
var interval = setInterval(function() {


  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: also take look here on how to declare variable in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var , no need to declare timer2 as jQuery object.

Comment: @AJ  what to do if count hour also for the formate like `1:30:00`

Comment: @alkavaghela : created a example fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/2dL6u5h5/1/  .. P.S : There are better javascript functions to achieve this, but  you can use this for reference, Feel free to ask if there are any doubt or questions regarding this logic... :)

Comment: @A.J - thank you for comments in above fiddle - can anyone also add comments to understand the javascript shorthand?

Comment: actually, i figured it out here: https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques ,  `if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 59 } else { seconds = seconds}`

Comment: How can I restart the timer?

Comment: One more issue with the script is when the time runs out it stops at -1:59 which is not correct. so for that what we can do is change the condition to something like this --->
minutes = (seconds < 0 && minutes > 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) clearInterval(interval);

Answer (score 20):

```js
var timer2 = "5:01";
var interval = setInterval(function() {


  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  //check if both minutes and seconds are 0
  if ((seconds <= 0) && (minutes <= 0)) clearInterval(interval);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

The above snippet will provide a countdown up to 0:00. The `clearInterval` function should be called at the end by checking whether minutes and seconds both are containing 0 as their value or not.

Comment: How can we add hour in the time left? Suppose, if we have 2 hours, 30 minutes & 20 seconds. 02:30:20. How can we show the count down?

Answer (score 4):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var minutes = 1, seconds = 59;
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("span.countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    var count = setInterval(function(){ if(parseInt(minutes) < 0) { clearInterval(count); } else {jQuery("span.countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds); if(seconds == 0) { minutes--; if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0"+minutes; seconds = 59;} seconds--; if(seconds < 10) minutes = "0"+seconds;} }, 1000);
  })
</script>
<span class="countdown"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var timer2 = $("5:01");
var timer = timer2.split(':');
```

you don't need to use jQuery wrap for string.
so, first of all fix this:

```
var timer2 = "5:01";
var timer = timer2.split(':');
```

and, the second you need to get out the start variable `5:01` because each your interval iteration reset the start value to `5:01`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var timer2 = "5:01";
var interval = setInterval(function() {


  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

how can you make stop in oo oo  instead -1:59

Answer (score 1):

here is an improved version of the one above. It allows counting of hours too, with unlimited hours possible. For example if you need to show two days and not waste space for showind days independently you can show 72h

It also has support for multiple timers on a page, each with their own intervals.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
var intervals = []; //prepare the intervals holder
function countdown(nr,initime,endtxt){
    var selector = ".timer";//actual class name will be .timer_123 (if nr=123)
    var timer2 = initime; //"71:10:07"; //unlimited hours
    
    intervals['countdown_'+nr] = setInterval(function() {
        var timer = timer2.split(':');
        //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
        var hours = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
        var minutes = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
        var seconds = parseInt(timer[2], 10);
        
        --seconds; //decrement secs first
        
        minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
        hours = (minutes < 0) ? --hours : hours;

            
        if (hours < 0 && minutes < 0 && seconds < 0) {
            clearInterval(intervals['countdown_'+nr]);
            $(selector+"_"+nr).html(endtxt);
        } else {
            //console.log(selector+"_"+nr, timer, timer2);
            
            //do 59 reset here to allow detection of negative values above
            seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
            minutes = (minutes < 0) ? 59 : minutes;         
            
            //set new timer value
            timer2 = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
            
            //start changes for display only
            seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
            minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes; 
            $(selector+"_"+nr).html(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
            
        } 
        
    }, 1000);   
}
</script>


Timer 1: <span class='timer timer_1'></span>
<script>countdown('1','72:23:13',"timer 1 has ended");</script>
<br>
Timer 2: <span class='timer timer_2'></span>
<script>countdown('2','24:00:00',"timer 2 has ended");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop on 00:00

```
var timer2 = "0:05";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var timer = timer2.split(':');
    //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
    var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
    --seconds;
    minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
    console.log(minutes, seconds);
    seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
    if (minutes < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
        timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Better put an explanation with your solution as well.