# I'm trying to make a countdown timer but the time won't post to my html correctly, what can I do to make this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var minutesLeft = 0;
var secondsLeft = 59;
var startMazeBtn = document.getElementById("startMazeBtn");
var setTimer;

// custom entry point for timer star
    entryPoint();
}
//timer function

function entryPoint () {
    handleTimer();
}

function startTimer () {
    console.log("startTimerFired");
    var min = minutesLeft;
    var sec = secondsLeft;
    if (sec >= 0) {
        $("#startTimer").text("00:" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec));
        sec --;
    } else if (min >= 0) {
        min - 60;
        sec + 59;
    } else {
        startTimer == 0;
    }
}

function handleTimer () {
    //setTimer = setInterval(() => startTimer, 1000);
    setTimer = setInterval(function() {
        startTimer();
        if(startTimer <= 0) {
            clearInterval(setTimer);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

```html
<!-- This is called in the html -->
<h3 class="startTimer" id="startTimer">00:00:00</h3>
```

I've tried changing the variables and attempted to log them but it always just runs the interval continually and doesn't display anything but 00:00:00. I'm trying to get it to that whatever I enter in the variables at the top of the js gets grabbed and processed

Comment: `startTimer == 0` -- what do you think that is doing?  `if(startTimer <= 0)` -- and what do you think THAT is doing?  Remembering that `startTimer` is a function object.

Comment: So startTimer == 0; should be set up as a variable instead of a conditional statement.

But as for the if statement it's not treating the function object with any sort of value this not giving me any clear condition

Comment: For reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035992/jquery-countdown-timer-for-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: for full length: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: The unmatched `}` after `entryPoint();` looks like a typo? And is likely causing everything to fail, ie nothing to run?  Have you checked your browser's devtools console for errors?  "*it always just runs the interval continually*" -  how do you know, what do you see?  "*doesn't display anything but 00:00:00*" - this would be true even if you had no JS on the page on the page, so it does not tell us anything about what the JS is doing.

Comment: No, `startTimer` is a FUNCTION.  You need to use a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to fix in your code and I have a few queries too.

1. Remove the extra `{` after `entryPoint` function.
2. On reason for HTML to be not updated is the statement `$("#startTimer").text` will run only for the first if block, `sec >= 0`.
3. I didn't understand what the `min - 60` and `sec + 59` logic means.
4. You didn't mention for how long you need to run the countdown.
5. You are not using hour so why use `00:00:00`?

**Important-**

1. The variables `min` and `sec` are in the local scope of `startTimer` function so every time this function is called, those variables will re-initialize with the same value which results in HTML being the same always. So, try updating the global variables `minutesLeft` and `secondsLeft`.
2. `startTimer` should not be both function and variable, try using the different variables to track the timer finish moment.

Here is a basic demo which will stop the timer after 1 minute.

```js
var minLeft = 0;
var secLeft = 60;
var minString;
var secString;
var finishTimer;

//timer function
handleTimer();

function startTimer() {
  if (secLeft == 0) {
    secLeft = 60;
    minLeft += 1;
  } else {
    secLeft--;
  }

  minStr = minLeft.toString().length > 1 ? minLeft : `0${minLeft}`
  secStr = secLeft.toString().length > 1 ? secLeft : `0${secLeft}`
  
  $("#startTimer").text("00:" + minStr + ":" + secStr)
}

function handleTimer() {
  finishTimer = setInterval(function() {
    startTimer();
    if (minLeft == 1) {
      console.log("Timer Stopped")
      clearInterval(finishTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is called in the html -->
<h3 class="startTimer" id="startTimer">00:00:00</h3>
```